# How to stable convert char* to TAO::String_Manager_T<char>

Tags: c++, ace, data-distribution-service, tao, opendds

I used OpenDDS's (DDS_HOME/tests/DCPS/Messenger) Publisher and Subscriber example.

In that source code, I just changed very simple code.
I want to put the message in `message.text`. But, it doesn't work.
Actually, when I input my word first time, It works well.
But, it doesn't work when I next input word.
I think it is related to memory allocation issues.

So, how can I convert `char*` to `TAO::String_Manager_T<char>` type?

Here is my part of source code and error message:

**Writer.cpp:**

```
Messenger::Message message;
message.subject_id = 99;

DDS::InstanceHandle_t handle = message_dw->register_instance(message);

static struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler=ctrlCfunc;
sigaction(SIGINT,&act,NULL);
/* We are all initialized, just service communications                  */

char userInput[255];
doIt=1;

message.from         = "Comic Book Guy";
message.subject      = "Review";
message.text         = "Worst. Movie. Ever.";
message.count        = 0;

while(doIt) {

    fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
    userInput[sizeof(userInput)-1]='\0';

    message.text=userInput;

  DDS::ReturnCode_t error;
  do {
    error = message_dw->write(message, handle);
  } while (error == DDS::RETCODE_TIMEOUT);

  if (error != DDS::RETCODE_OK) {
    ACE_ERROR((LM_ERROR,
               ACE_TEXT("%N:%l: svc()")
               ACE_TEXT(" ERROR: write returned %d!\n"), error));
  }

  message.count++;
}
```

Publisher side error:

```
# ./publisher -DCPSInfoRepo 210.107.212.75:12345 -DCPSConfigFile rtps_uni.ini
Starting publisher
(7352|140545985509184) NOTICE: using DCPSInfoRepo value from command option (overrides value if it's in config file).
Starting publisher with 1 args
(7352|140545985509184) WARNING: Could not find FQDN. Using "127.0.0.1" as fully qualified hostname, please correct system configuration.
Reliable DataWriter
Creating Writer
Starting Writer
testbug0
testbug1
*** Error in `./publisher': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd35d37dcb0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fd3677427e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fd36774b37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fd36774f53c]
/home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/ACE_wrappers/lib/libTAO.so.2.2a_p12(_ZN5CORBA11string_freeEPc+0x2c)[0x7fd36878e1dc]
./publisher[0x4063dc]
./publisher[0x409f91]
./publisher[0x4094e7]
/home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.so.6.2a_p12(_ZN13ACE_Task_Base7svc_runEPv+0x54)[0x7fd3683ccebc]
/home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.so.6.2a_p12(_ZN18ACE_Thread_Adapter8invoke_iEv+0x113)[0x7fd3683cd52d]
/home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.so.6.2a_p12(_ZN18ACE_Thread_Adapter6invokeEv+0xc7)[0x7fd3683cd3d1]
/home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.so.6.2a_p12(ace_thread_adapter+0x2b)[0x7fd368338cb7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7fd367a9c6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fd3677d23dd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 140986                             /home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/tests/DCPS/Messenger/publisher
0060e000-0060f000 r--p 0000e000 08:01 140986                             /home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/tests/DCPS/Messenger/publisher
0060f000-00610000 rw-p 0000f000 08:01 140986                             /home/user/Desktop/OpenDDS-3.11/tests/DCPS/Messenger/publisher
00610000-00611000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00667000-00787000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fd33c000000-7fd33c022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd33c022000-7fd340000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd344000000-7fd344022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd344022000-7fd348000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd348000000-7fd348022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd348022000-7fd34c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd34c000000-7fd34c022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd34c022000-7fd350000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd350000000-7fd350022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd350022000-7fd354000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd354000000-7fd354022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Subscriber side error:

```
# ./subscriber -DCPSConfigFile rtps_uni.ini
(9370|140579829053248) WARNING: Could not find FQDN. Using "127.0.0.1" as fully qualified hostname, please correct system configuration.
Transport is RELIABLE
Reliable DataReader
DataReaderListener.cpp:151: INFO: on_subscription_matched()
SampleInfo.sample_rank = 0
SampleInfo.instance_state = 1
ERROR: Repeat Message: subject    = Review
         subject_id = 99
         from       = Comic Book Guy
         count      = 0
         text       = testbug0

ERROR: Invalid message.text
```

Comment: *message.text=userInput;* -- What do you think this line does?  It doesn't do what you think it does.  Also, what is `text` declared as?

Comment: `Messenger::Message` is TAO support library. And `message.text` 's type is  `TAO::String_Manager_T<char>`. I just want to insert my word in `TAO::String_Manager_T<char>` type.

Comment: if write() is executed in thread / asynchronous maybe all structures are non-existing when main work is executed

Comment: Jacek, you mean, when the program run main thread, all structures are initialized. is it right??

Comment: but when fuction returns, all structures are lost (but pointers somewhere exist) / I see solution with str_dup(), yes, this is the same way of thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

I use `message.text= CORBA::string_dup(userInput);`

instead of `message.text= userInput;`